# Is there any way to capture complete browser screen using java or javascript?

Tags: java

I want to capture complete browser, I am using below code to take screenshot....

```
function takeSnapShot($filename)
{
    try 
    {
            var robot = new java.awt.Robot();
            var toolkit = new java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            var screenSize = toolkit.getScreenSize();
            var screenRect = new java.awt.Rectangle(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
            var image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            var file = new java.io.File("D:/"+$filename+".png");
            javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        }
    catch (e) 
    {
            Packages.java.lang.System.out.println(e);
        }
}
```

But it is capturing only visible part of the browser....so is there any way to capture complete browser screen?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: I can never figure why programmers want to take perfectly good (or bad, as the case may be) HTML and transform it into an image.  While a picture speaks a thousand words, a static image of a web page takes a (couple of) thousand bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do that in pure java, you gonna have to take multiple screenshots and merge them. Not a simple job. I dont know any library that can help you.

The simplest way to solve your problem is by using a screenshot application and just call it from you java application. Take a look at CutyCapt http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/